# Google Calendar API - How to get sharing links for a calendar, inparticular the private ical url?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps, icalendar

When adding a google calendar with the google calendar api v3 i don't find any option to get any of the sharing links for the calendar.

From what I see in the settings panel of the calendar there are following links:

- sharing link:
  consists of a cid - the base64 encoded calendar id
  always leads to your personal calendar webapp where you are asked to subscribe 
  to this calendar
- webview of the calendar:
  consists of the cal id and leads to a webview of the calendar, either when cal 
  is public or your got the rights to see it with your account
- iframe embedding html: might only work when cal is public
- ical public link: provides an ical file to integrate into any cal app (iOS, 
  Outlook ...), provides ical file only then cal is publicly shared.
- ical private link: includes a hash code that makes only people with this link 
  able to request the ical file, regardless of what privacy setting the cal is 
  set.

One might cunstruct some oft the sharing links, however you can't construct the private ics link, since it includes the security hash.

However, since I'd like to share my cal's ical file via my app with none google users while I don't want to set the cal sharing to public I will need to get the private ical link - probably via the API, but I can't find any option for this in the API docs ... does anyone know how to solve this issue?